# Accurately detect color regions in an image using K-means clustering

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 2d, k-means, image-segmentation

I'm using K-means clustering in color-based image segmentation. I have a 2D image which has 3 colors, black, white, and green. Here is the image,

[image]

I want K-means to produce 3 clusters, one represents the green color region, the second one represents the white region, and the last one represents the black region.

Here is the code I used,

```
%Clustering color regions in an image. 

%Step 1: read the image using imread, and show it using imshow. 

img =  (imread('img.jpg'));

figure, imshow(img), title('X axis rock cut'); %figure is for creating a figure window.
text(size(img,2),size(img,1)+15,...
     'Unconventional shale x axis cut', ...
     'FontSize',7,'HorizontalAlignment','right');

 %Step 2: Convert Image from RGB Color Space to L*a*b* Color Space
 conversionform = makecform('srgb2lab'); %the form of the conversion is defined as from rgb to l a b
 lab_img = applycform(img,conversionform); %converting the rgb image to l a b image using the conversion form defined above.

 %Step 3: Classify the Colors in 'a*b*' Space Using K-Means Clustering
 ab = double(lab_img(:,:,2:3));
 nrows = size(ab,1);
 ncols = size(ab,2);
 ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);

 nColors = 3;
% repeat the clustering 3 times to avoid local minima
[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean', ...
                                      'Replicates',3);
%Step 4: Label Every Pixel in the Image Using the Results from KMEANS

%For every object in your input, kmeans returns an index corresponding to a cluster. The cluster_center output from kmeans will be used later in the example. Label every pixel in the image with its cluster_index.

pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
figure, imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');

segmented_images = cell(1,3);
rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 3]);

for k = 1:nColors
    color = img;
    color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
    segmented_images{k} = color;
end

figure, imshow(segmented_images{1}), title('objects in cluster 1');
figure, imshow(segmented_images{2}), title('objects in cluster 2');
figure, imshow(segmented_images{3}), title('objects in cluster 3');
```

But I'm not getting the results as required. I get one cluster with green regions, one cluster with green region boundaries, and one with gray, black, and white colors. Here are the resulting clusters.

[image]

The aim of doing this is that after getting the correct clustering results, **I want to count the number of pixels in every region using the concept of connected components.**

So, my aim is to know how many pixels there are in every color region. I tried another simpler way by getting the matrix of the 2D image and trying to figure out the number of pixels for every color. However, I found more than 3 RGB colors in the matrix, maybe because pixels of the same color have a slightly different color levels. That's why I went to image segmentation.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix the code above in order to get the required results?

I would also appreciate it if you give me hints on how to do this in an easier way, if there is any.

EDIT: Here is a code I made to iterate over every pixel in the image. Please notice I use 4 colors red, yellow, blue, and white instead of green, white, and black, but the idea is the same. `rgb2name` is the function that returns the color name given RGB color.

```
im= imread ('img.jpg'); 

[a b c] = size (im); 
%disp ([a b]);
yellow=0; 
blue=0; 
white=0; 
red=0; 


for i=1:a
    for j=1:b
        x= impixel(im, i, j)/255 ;
        color= rgb2name (x);
        if (~isempty (strfind (color, 'yellow')))
            yellow= yellow+1; 
        elseif (~isempty (strfind(color, 'red')))
            red= red+1; 
        elseif (~isempty (strfind (color, 'blue')))
            blue= blue+1; 
        elseif (~isempty (strfind (color, 'white')))
           white= white+1; 
        else 
            %disp ('warning'); break; 
        end            
        disp (color);
        disp (i);
    end
end
disp (yellow)
disp (red)
disp (blue)
disp (white)
```

Thank You.

Comment: That's because in your image you don't have exactly 3 colors. Due to jpg compression, you create artifacts near sharp edges that generates other colors. In addition, in Lab space a and b are not very discriminant in this image. If you can post a uncompressed (like png) image it'll be much easier (don't convert from jpg to png, but save the image directly in png from your data).

Comment: Thanks @Miki, I have tried to run the code with png image, but I'm still getting the same results. Is there any easier way to count the pixels in every color region? I wrote a code that reads every pixel in the 2D image, then calls a function (a ready function in .m file which I downloaded) that returns the color name using nearest neighbor approach. But the image has 655 X 653 pixels, so it takes too much time, I've been running it for 2 hours and it didn't finish until now. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: You can count the number of pixels for every color pretty fast. The problem here is that you don't have just 3 color! So you have a few options: 1) work on an uncompressed image (with no compression artifacts); 2) find the 3 _dominant_ colors, and assign antialiasing-generated colors to one of them. I strongly suggest 1). If you have access to original data it'll be a lot simpler. In case if you can't do 1), do the colors (black, white, green) be always exactly the same?

Comment: Thanks @Miki, I only have a .jpg image. The function that I have downloaded contains many RGB color variations and it can find the colors. No, the colors are not the same, each color may have a slightly different multiple levels. To solve this, I removed all the color values in the function, and kept those which correspond to green, black, and white. No need for many levels, because the function uses nearest neighbor approach. My problem is that I iterate through the pixels using 2 for loops (655 X 653 iterations), this takes too long time. Is there a way to get rid of the loops? Thanks.

Comment: Post the code containing the two nested loops

Comment: @Miki, I posted the code, please check it. Thank you.

Comment: Wow, what an overkill :D . Just to be clear: 1) you want to know the number of white, green, and black pixels (where pixels of other colors will sum up with the nearest neighbor color). 2) you know a priori what color you have (white, black, green) or there may be any 3 different colors? Now I have to go, when I'll back I'll post a solution according to your answer to these questions.

Comment: Thanks @Miki, yes it is :D. 1) I only have yellow, red, white, and blue. The colors green, black, and white are just examples in the question Any RGB value in the image will be mapped to some color. For example, even if there is a light blue, it will be mapped to blue, because only blue is available to represent any blue level. So, the nearest neighbor to light blue will be blue. 2) Yes, I have red, yellow, blue, and white only. Visually, you see only one level for each, but the function produces different levels. Thus, I defined only one level for every color. OK I'll be waiting. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my approach to count the number of pixels in every region. Given that (as discussed in the comments):

- the value (RGB) and the number (K) of colors are known a priori
- compression artifacts and anti-aliasing generated additional colors, that must be considered as the nearest-neighbor among the K know colors.

Since you know a priori the colors, you don't need k-means. It could actually lead to bad results as in your question. The approach of @crowdedComputeeer take care of this aspect.

You can compute nearest neighbor with `pdist2` directly on the pixel values. There's no need to use the really slow function that looks for the color name.

Here is the code. You can change the number and values of colors simply modifying the variable `colors`. This will compute the number of pixels in each color, and output the masks.

```
img =  (imread('path_to_image'));

colors = [  0 0 0;    % black
            0 1 0;    % green
            1 1 1];   % white


% % You can change the colors        
% colors = [  0 0 1;    % red
%             1 1 0;    % yellow
%             1 0 0;    % blue
%             1 1 1];   % white


% Find nearest neighbour color
list = double(reshape(img, [], 3)) / 255;
[~, IDX] = pdist2(colors, list, 'euclidean', 'Smallest', 1);
% IDX contains the indices to the nearest element


N = zeros(size(colors, 1), 1);
for i = 1 : size(colors, 1)
    % Count the number of pixels for each color
    N(i) = sum( IDX == i );
end

% This will display the number of pixels for each color
disp(N);



% Eventually build the masks
indices = reshape(IDX, [size(img,1), size(img,2)]);

figure();
szc = size(colors,1);
for i = 1 : szc
    subplot(1,szc,i);
    imagesc(indices == i);
end
```

Resulting counts:

```
97554     % black
16894     % green
31852     % white
```

Resulting masks:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot this is great. But, I have a red color (not exact red) in the image, and I get the count of red=0. Why is that happening? Thank you.

Comment: @Dania can you share that image so I could figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share it, because it is not mine. Can we include different red levels in the array? Maybe that way it can capture it?

Comment: @Dania you can 1) check the values of your "almost red" pixels, and use that values for "red" in the array. 2) add as many colors you want in `colors` (beware that the number `K` would increase).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try that. By k do you mean the count for every color?

Comment: @Dania you divide your image in K colors (K = 4 for red,yellow,blue,white). This corresponds to the rows of `colors`. If you add a color (e.g. dark red, red, yellow, blue, white) then K becomes 5, and you're are effectively dividing the pixels in 5 groups.

Answer (score 3):

I thought this problem was very interesting, so I apologize ahead of time if the answer is a little overboard. In short, k-means is the right strategy, in general, for problems where you want to segment an image into a discrete color space. But, your example image, which contains primarily only three colors, each of which is well separated in color space, is easily segmented using only a histogram. See below for segmenting using thresholds.

You can easily get the pixel counts by summing each matrix. e.g., `bCount = sum(blackPixels(:))`

```
filename = '379NJ.png';
x = imread(filename); 
x = double(x); % cast to floating point
x = x/max(max(max(x))); % normalize

% take histogram of green dimension
g = x(:, :, 2);
c = hist(g(:), 2^8);

% smooth the hist count 
c = [zeros(1, 10), c, zeros(1, 10)];
N = 4;
for i = N+1:length(c) - N; 
   d(i - N) = mean(c(i -N:i)); 
end
d = circshift(d, [1, N/2]);

% as seen in histogram, the three colors fall nicely into 3 peaks
figure, plot(c, '.-');
[~, clusterCenters] = findpeaks(d, 'MinPeakHeight', 1e3);

% set the threshold halfway between peaks 
boundaries = [floor((clusterCenters(2) - clusterCenters(1))/2), ...
                 clusterCenters(2) + floor((clusterCenters(3) - clusterCenters(2))/2)];
thresh1 = boundaries(1)*ones(size(g))/255;
thresh2 = boundaries(2)*ones(size(g))/255;

% categorize based on threshold
blackPixels = g < thresh1;
greenPixels = g >= thresh1 & g < thresh2;
whitePixels = g >= thresh2;
```

[image: Image segmentation]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried to run the code, but I got an error for x = double(x)/(max(max(max(double)))) saying that input arguments are not enough. So I've made it as x= double (x) and I run the code. Is it correct? Also, when I run the code I get a blue curve representing two peaks. Is this what I should get or I did something wrong? One more thing please, I have another image with yellow, blue, red, and white. I want to know the number of the first 3 colors (white is what remains). So we have 3 clusters. Can I use the same code you posted or I need to change it?

Comment: I fixed the typo that gave you the error. After you run the code, try imshow for each of the *Pixels variables. They should look like the attached figures. Also, please note, as mentioned in my answer, this strategy works for the image you gave, it is not intended to be general. However, if an image is segregated into a small ( say 5 or less) set of distinct colors, then segmenting via a histogram should work fine. But, it will likely need tweaking for each case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about detecting yellow, red, and blue. I apologize if this is a basic question, but I'm still a beginner. Can I do that, what thresholds do I need? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this project](https://github.com/IbraDje/K-Means-FCM-Images/blob/master/K-Means%20Clustering.py) could help, please take a try.