# How to segment a color image using K-means clustering?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, k-means, image-segmentation

I am working on a project that performs segmentation by k-means clustering. I have to apply K-means clustering for K = [2, 3, 4, ... K-max] and calculate the average distance of each point to its cluster center. Also, I have to determine K* for which this distance does not change much when switched to K* + 1. Kmax=20.

As far as I wrote down code is below. My first concern arise did i do something wrong?

```
I = imread('image');
imshow(I);

Id = im2double(I);

red = I(:,:,1);
green = I(:,:,2);
blue = I(:,:,3);
[c, r] = meshgrid(1:size(I,1), 1:size(I,2));
X = [red(:) green(:) blue(:) red(:) c(:)];


K     = 2:20;                      %Cluster Numbers
[IDX, C, SUMD] = kmeans(X, K);
ave_dist(K) = sum(SUMD(:))/number_of_pixels_in_image;
```

1) How am i going to plot the average distance to cluster centers as a function of K?

2) How do i determine the smallest K* for which

```
`| ave_dist(K*) - ave_dist(K*+1) |< THR_K.  THR_K = 100`
```

Thank you.

Comment: Matlab? Might want to add the tag.

Comment: yes thank you very much sir, somehow i have forgotton that ..

Comment: Have a look at [THIS SO QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034344/accurately-detect-color-regions-in-an-image-using-k-means-clustering?rq=1)

Comment: Why are you using `red`  twice and `c`in your `X`?

Comment: Second one is in the data vector for used to determine [IDX, C, SUMD]= kmeans(X,K);

Comment: @jeru +1,dude, i dont know how to thank you cause it resolves much :)

Comment: @aod +1 for what? I didn't get you....

Comment: @jeru for leading to another way that might be very useful for my problem?

Comment: glad i could help :)

Comment: @jeru it really helped but just can you help me with 2nd question of mine ?

Answer (score 0):

1st question: You're building a vector `ave_dist` that you can use directly with `plot(ave_dist)`

2nd question: You can use `find` for that: `index = find(abs(ave_dist(1:end-1)-ave_dist(2:end)) <= 100,1,'first')`

Comment: I have to find a plot or diagram that should be in 3-D vector system. such as https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour3.html here but it should   plot the average distance to cluster centers. and for the first question: I must have forgotton that also there must be a threshold value for k equals 100

Comment: If this is not what you wanted, it is still a bit unclear to me what you need. Could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: ofcourse i can explain it again. I have an image with dominant colors red,green,blue,yellow and white. I need extract the R, G and B components of the image which i did then assign to a data matrix. For K = 2: Kmax (Kmax=20) and must use kmeans function to obtain the cluster indices of each pixel (IDX) and within-cluster sums of point-to-centroid distances (SUMD). Then my 1st and 2nd questions comes. K* automatically from the ave_dist vector that cannot be find by ave_dist function.